# (Almost) Impossible Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I'm reading a book called [(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series](https://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/almost_impossible_integrals_sums_and_series_by_valean_cornel_ioan_z-lib.org_.pdf) of Cornel Ioan Vălean

As a solution of two integrals he writes the limits of some $2n$-th derivatives functions: (pag. 14 and pag. 77)

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}(\ln(1+x)\ln(1-x))^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{4}\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{\partial^{2n}}{\partial x^n\partial y^n}2^{x+y}\text{B}(x,y)$$
and
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x}\ln(x)^{2n}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{4}(1-4^{-n})\zeta(2n+1)(2n)!+\frac{(2n)!}{2}\beta(2n+2)+\frac{\pi}{16}\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n}}{\mathrm{d}s^{2n}}\left[\frac{\psi\left(\frac{1-s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3-s}{4}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}+\frac{\psi\left(\frac{2-s}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{4-s}{4}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}+2\pi\csc(\pi s)\right]$$

Where:

1. $\text{B}(x,y)$ is the Beta function;
2. $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function;
3. $\beta(z)$ is the Dirichlet beta function;
4. $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function.

How is it possible to calculate those limits?

Comment: Who said it is possible?

Comment: In other words, in the PDF's pages 50 and 111 we have respectively your second equation (problem 1.24 part ii), solved on pp. 140-146) and your first equation (a generalization to problem 1.8 parts i) & ii), pp. 40/41, from which they are proven).